# Scanner useDelimiter question

Tags: java, regex

In `useDelimiter("[^A-Z]+")` what does the `^` stand for?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[^abc]  Any character except a, b, or c (negation)

From:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: i had a look. the documentation says: "Boundary matchers ^ The beginning of a line." I tried it out and it does indeed only return words, discarding numbers

Comment: The meaning of the `^` metacharacter is different inside and outside a character class. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

Anything except A through Z and only once.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a character class (the [] brackets), the ^ character at the start means that the character class is NOT the following characters

so [0-9] means match any number, [^0-9] means match anything that is NOT a number. [^A] would mean everything but an A and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a character class the `^` negates the meaning of the class if it is the first character in the class (as others have pointed out).

Outside a character class, the `^` is an anchor assertion that matches the (zero-width) location at the beginning of the string (or the location immediately after a `\n` newline if `multi-line` mode is on).